# decorator for initializing dataclass field metadata

Tags: python-3.7, python-decorators, python-dataclasses

using python3.7 `dataclass`, I am able to write something like:

```python
class Foo:
    fuzz: int = field(default=0, metadata={'ns_unit': 'km'})
    bazz: str = field(default='', metadata={'ns_prefix': 'xx_', 'ns_other': 1})
```

Those metadata are used somewhere else. What I would like is to have a way to use decorators to set the metadata, e.g.:

```python
class Foo:
    @ns(unit='km')
    fuzz: int = 0
    @ns(prefix='xx_', other=1)
    bazz: str = field(default='')
```

I is possible to achieve ?

Comment: No, the decorator syntax doesn't allow for decorating assignment, even in class bodies.  The `ns` function your write will have to go on the right hand side of the assignment: `bazz: str = ns('', prefix='xx_', other=1)`